# Vlookup with dynamic range in VBA issue in defining the range

Tags: excel, vba

```
VLookup(A1,ProblemID_afterDupl!A$:B" & LR1 & ",2,false)
```

I'm using the above formula however it's not working for me.

P.S = LR1 is the variable where I have stored the last row

Comment: You need to use the indirect function to reference a range dynamically. But if it's just the last row you could also reference the full col's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Range("B1").Select

Set prob = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ProblemID_afterDupl")
Set rand = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Random Transpose")
Set dataRng = prob.Range("A2:B" & LR1)

For y = 1 To Sample

rand.Range("B" & y).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup( _
    rand.Range("A" & y).Value, dataRng, 2, False)
    
Next y
```

I used the loop as well as indirect references...Thank you for the help